# Input file miltiple ограничение на максимум 10 файлов

Tags: javascript, jquery, валидация, es5

```
<div class="form-file">
    <label class="form-file-label">
        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" data-form-file-input="">
        <span class="form-file__text" data-form-file-btn="">Add photo first form</span>
    </label>
    <div class="form-file__list" data-form-file-list=""></div>
</div>
```

Смотреть тут

https://codepen.io/atmiura/pen/JjWrrMP

Нужно чтобы в форму можно было добавлять максимум 10 файлов и плюс проверка на размер и тип файлов. Последние два работают, но вот 10 файлов никак не могу додуматься как сделать.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
    $("input[type='submit']").click(function(){
        var $fileUpload = $("input[type='file']");
        if (parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length)>10){
         alert("You can only upload a maximum of 10 files");
        }
    });    
});
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple />

<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

Как-то так

Comment: Спасибо, но не то) нужно именно при добавлении